# MKOverlay update flashing

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, mkoverlay

In my app, I use an MKPolyline to track the user's path. Sometimes (and not all the time, which I don't understand), when a new line segment gets added to the map, the entire line flashes. Sometimes it doesn't. This is the code being used to add the lines:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coords[2];

coords[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

coords[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude);

MKPolyline* line = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coords count:2];

[mapView addOverlay:line];
```

Am I missing something?

**Edit: This usually happens upon the app's return from being sent to the background. I'm not exactly sure why, though, because I am only adding an overlay, not modifying the entire mapView.overlays array. ...right?**

Comment: So is it when a new segment gets added or hen the app returns from the background? Maybe a combination of the two?

Comment: It happens when new segments are added after returning from the background. Would it have something to do with the fact that the segments are added from a background thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be related, but Apple does state in the [Managing the Map's Overlay Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW20) section of the Location Awareness Programming Guide...

> Because the map view is an interface item, any modifications to the
>   `overlays` array should be synchronized and performed on the
>   application’s main thread.

Comment: Yes, I think that might just be the problem; I have had other problems with CLLocationManager and threading when the app enters the background.

Comment: Yes, I do think that this solved the problem. I'll have to do a few more tests to be sure of it though.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to try to get the flash over with before you show the map to the user.

Try one of the following:

```
[mapView setNeedsDisplay];
```

or

```
if ([[mapView overlays] count] > 0){
    [[[mapView overlays] lastObject] setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Put these in either your "viewWillAppear" method, or the "applicationWillEnterForeground" method in AppDelegate.m.

Comment: But the problem is that it shouldn't be flashing at all- sometimes the flashing occurs and sometimes it doesn't.